# Not importing shape in python

Tags: python

Hi write this game and the screen is import but the shape not import 
this is code and it's run with any error

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)


# Main game loop
 while True:
    wn.update()
# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350,0)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Because you've got an endless loop above it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic of the posted code is flawed, you set the `turtle` object at the beginning and it appears (as it should). but then you use an endless loop that `update` the object but there is nothing to update.

so the code after the loop is never executed -> no shape will appear

So doing the following will show the expected result, getting rid of the infinite loop:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800,height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350,0)

wn.update()
```